# ImageMagick apply shadow effect in bulk

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to apply a drop shadow effect to some files i have in a folder. Similar to whats done in Photoshop but I'm trying to apply in bulk.

[image: Original Picture]

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image: Border applied]

Does anyone have any tips on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Edited

I discovered the below script but this turns out as below and also changes the dimensions of the image.

```
convert -page +4+4 "old.png" -alpha set \( +clone -background navy -shadow 60x8+8+8 \) +swap -background none -mosaic "new.png"
```

[image: Test result]

Answer (score 0):

To make a shadow, you need two images. Mogrify does not allow that. So you would have to write a script FOR loop over your folder of images and do for each:

`convert red_blue.png \( +clone  -background black  -shadow 80x20-20+0 \) +swap -background none -layers merge  +repage red_blue_shadow.png`

[image]
See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow